# Stochastic Comparability

Tags: stochastic-ordering

I have ran into a paper where the author speaks of finding the variance for the AUC (Area Under the ROC curve) for two continuous variables X and Y, which are ***stochastically comparable*** .

Does anybody have an idea what does ***stochastically comparable*** mean?

> This is the reference to the paper: Bamber, D. (1975). The area above
> the ordinal dominance graph and the area below the receiver operating
> characteristic graph. Journal of Mathematical Psychology, 12(4),
> 387–415. https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-2496(75)90001-2
> **pages: 17-19**

And this is a paper quoted within this reference:

> Birnbaum, Z. W.; Klose, Orval M. Bounds for the Variance of the Mann-Whitney Statistic. Ann. Math. Statist. 28 (1957), no. 4, 933--945. doi:10.1214/aoms/1177706794. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177706794

Comment: No idea. But perhaps you can provide the reference of the paper?

Comment: Hi Alex, I'v added references, as you you can now see in the question